# How to skip cert check in python wrapper for Cloudflare?

Tags: python, cloudflare

I am using python wrapper for Cloudflare "python-cloudflare" and getting [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] error

```
cf = CloudFlare.CloudFlare(debug=DEBUG, token=configurations["token"])
accounts = cf.accounts.get()
```

How to skip SSL cert check in python wrapper for Cloudflare ? I would expect param like verify=False, but this is not a valid option

```
Python Cloudflare API v4 - DEBUG - Call: requests exception! "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.cloudflare.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /client/v4/accounts (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')))"
```

Comment: why does it fail? Skipping cert checks is insecure.

Comment: I don't know why it fails. And still I want to skip

Comment: I mean ..It fails because self signed cert in chain. And I want it to skip cert verification at least in dev process

Comment: I am not sure what this tool is supposed to do, but I am pretty sure that Cloudflare wouldn't use a self-signed certificate for any official public service. Perhaps this error should make you worry and find out why its doing that.